# Using string functions (.substr) on arrays of strings

Tags: c++

I have an array of strings, and need to grab substrings (the strings in between commas, in this case) and put them into another array of strings.

I declare it as `strings[numberOfTapes]`, so when I am searching for the commas I go character by character in a nested for loop, like so:

```
for(int j = 0; j < tapes[i].length(); j++){
   if(tapes[i][j] == ','){
      input[counter2] = tapes[i][j].substr(i-counter, counter);
   }
}
```

For which I get the following error:

```
request for member 'substr' in tapes[i].std::basic_string::operator[]
[with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocated]
(((long unsigned int)))', which is of non class type 'char'
```

I'm going through the string character by character with `j`. Is there a way to get `.substr` to work with the `tapes[i][j]` format, or do I need to implement this differently to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tapes[i][j]` is the character `','`, and that character has no `substr` method. You probably wanted to call `substr` on the string object `tapes[i]`, not on the single character.

Also: You call `substr(i-counter, counter)` after you found a comma at position `j`. Is that your intention?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an array of strings, tapes[i][j] will access a char, not the string that you wish to substring, you probably want tapes[i].substr...

Answer (score 0):

If comma(,) is used as a delimiter in your case, why not using some function which splits the strings based on a delimiter?

I can think of using something like strtok() function to split them based on comma(,).

Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

Using higher-level tools rather than individually iterating each string in a sequence of strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  istringstream input ("sample,data,separated,by,commas");
  vector<string> data;
  for (string line; getline(input, line, ',');) {
    data.push_back(line);
  }

  cout << "size: " << data.size() << '\n';
  for (size_t n = 0; n != data.size(); ++n) {
    cout << data[n] << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also look at std::string's various methods (it has a lot, described as "too many plus the kitchen sink"), you can use [find](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to simplify your loop as a first step.